# How to automatically login users after Email/Password authentication

Tags: authentication, next.js, mongodb-realm

I'm currently building a blog sample app, using NextJS, ApolloClient and MongoDB + MongoRealm. The NextJS skeleton was built after the framework's official page tutorial.
At the moment, new users can signup, by accessing a SignUp form which is routed at 'pages/signup'. After entering their credentials, they are redirected to the home page. Then, the freshly signed in users have to visit another page(the one associated with 'pages/login' root), which contains the login form, which is responsible with their email/password authentication.
Also, I've set up Realm to send a confirmation email at the user's email address. The email contains a link to a customized page from my NextJs app, which will handle their confirmation(users also have to be confirmed, after requesting a sign in)

The workflow should be established with this. However, I want to automatically login a user, after he/she just logged in(so that they won't need to sign in and also visit the log in page, when creating their accounts).

The problem I'm encountering is that my React component that handles the user confirmation, doesn't have access to the user instance's email and password. I need a way to login the user, without having access to his/her credentials.

Below, I will try to explain exactly why this access restriction happens in the first place. Although the entire '_app.js' is wrapped in some custom providers, I'll try to keep things as simple as possible, so I'll present only what is needed for this topic.

My signup.js file looks something like this:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
// Used 'useForm' hook to simplify data extraction from the //input form
import { useAuth } from "members";

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
  const { signup } = useAuth();

  const signUpAndRedirect = (form) => {
  signup(form.email, form.password);
  router.push("/");
  // after signing up, redirect client back to home
  };

  return (
{/*My form's 'email' and 'password' fields are only accessible in the SignUpForm component*/}
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(signUpAndRedirect)}>
        ...
       ...
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

My login.js file is built after the same concept, the only difference being that 'signUpAndRedirect' is replaced with
'authenticateAndRedirect':

```
const authenticateAndRedirect = (form) => {
    login(form.email, form.password);
    router.push("/");
  };
```

And here is my confirm.js file, which is responsible with extracting the token and tokenId from the confirmation URL. This component is normally only rendered when the client receives the email and clicks on the confirmation link(which basically has the form /confirm, where each token is a string and is added into the URL by Realm).

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useAuth } from "members";

const Confirm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { confirm, login } = useAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = router.query.token;
    const tokenId = router.query.tokenId;

    if (token && tokenId) {
      confirm(token, tokenId);
      login(email, password); // !!! I don't have access to these
    }
  }, [router]);
//used useEffect() to assure the confirmation only happens once, after the component was rendered.

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Thank you for confirming your email. Your profile was      successfully
        activated.
      </h2>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>Go back to home</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Confirm;
```

And finally, just a quick look into the signup, login and confirm methods that I have access to through my customized providers. I am quite positive that they work correctly:

```
const client = () => {
  const { app, credentials } = useRealm();
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(app.currentUser || false);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(user ? true : false);

  
  // Login and logout using email/password.

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const userCredentials = await credentials(email, password);
      await app.logIn(userCredentials);

      setCurrentUser(app.currentUser);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      setUser(null);

      // Sign out from Realm and Auth0.
      await app.currentUser?.logOut();
      // Update the user object.
      setCurrentUser(app.currentUser);
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      setUser(false);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };

  const signup = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(email, password);
      // await app.emailPasswordAuth.resendConfirmation(email);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };

  const confirm = async (token, tokenId) => {
    try {
      await app.emailPasswordAuth.confirmUser(token, tokenId);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };

  return {
    currentUser,
    login,
    logout,
    signup,
    confirm,
  };
};

export default client;
```

The currentUser will basically represent the Realm.app.currentUser and will be provided to the _app by my providers.

So, the problem is that my Confirm component doesn't have access to the email and password fields.
I've tried to use the useContext hook, to pass data between sibling components, but quickly abandoned this approach, because I don't want to pass sensitive data throughout my NextJS pages(The only place where I should use the password is during the MongoDB POST request, since it gets encrypted by Realm Web).

Is there any way I could solve this issue? Maybe an entirely different approach?

Thank you very much in advance! Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: authentication happen on the BACK-END. and you will need to check your PLAIN user password against the HASHED  password stored in your database. you locally store a TOKEN generated by your auth methods

Comment: Thanks for commenting! :) Indeed, normally it happens on the server. However, ApolloClient and MongoDB Realm provide you the opportunity to authenticate directly from the client, using some dependencies and node.js packages that are bundled into the NextJs app. The Apollo client basically queries(using GraphQL) the Mongo Realm "interface", which in turn communicates with Atlas. I don't store passwords into Atlas. At the moment, I store them in Realm, but this will change, after transitioning to JWT authentication.

Comment: I've managed to successfully create and authenticate users into my app, the only problem is that I wanted users to login as soon as they'd created their account. Not a vital problem, still, perhaps I'll leave it that way, if I won't be able to find any new approaches

Comment: You can find more about ApolloClient and React here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/ The entire Mongo-related documentation is pretty sparse, though, kind a pain to get through it

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the user email confirmation, you could potentially call the login function when the register is finished like that :

```js
registerAndLogin(email, password)
 .then(() => 
      loginAndRedirect(email, password)
      .then(() => router.push('/')
      .catch(err => throw err)
  )
 .catch(err => throw err)
```

I used your post to resolve an error I had, so thank you by the way.
Hope my answer works, I didn't had the time to test.

Comment: Hi, Benjamin! Thanks for answering! Glad you found my post useful! :) In the end, I had to use Google Firebase authentication, so the user creation process is now handled by the service. I will try, however, your idea after finishing more urgent stuff. What I think it's simpler and usually used in general is just to redirect the user to the login page, after confirmation. So just a ```router.push(/login)``` should be enough

Comment: Could you by any chance provide your complete authentication (useAuth && useRealm) code, beacuse there is so little documentation on Realm auth ... You seem to have quite made it though. Maybe I will also have to switch to Firebase because it is much more documented !

Comment: Sure! No problem with that! Here is my Git: https://github.com/BaladaRock/Next.js-tutorial-blog

Comment: I've got some help from some experienced friends of mine! :) But the point is to wrap you entire application inside a 'Realm Provider', an 'Apollo client provider' and a 'Cache provider'. This is because you'll have to have access to your current user-related info throughout the app. Also, without a Realm instance, you won't be able to talk to Mongo. But, just to make sure everything is clear, maybe best is to clone my repo, run 'npm install' and try to follow along the code. You can check the corresponding branch, for what you need. Feel free to ask me any questions :).